# Apache CXF - http-centric approach and PUT from client to server

Tags: java, http, jax-ws, cxf, jax-rs

I use Apache CXF to provide communication with a RESTful API.

I need to use a PUT method to send some constrained entities to database via the API.

Is this the right way to provide this method?

I ask because I am getting a HTTP 500 error code response.

I can only find GET method examples in the official Apache CXF documentation; HTTP PUT, HTTP POST etc. are missing.

```
WebClient client = 
         WebClient.create("http://MY_SERVER:9090/admission/services/processing");
Admission a = new Admission();
a.setCode("73935282");
:
:

Response r = client.path("/admission").put(a);
// Here I would like to get 201, but there is 500 :(
System.out.println("response: " + r.getStatus());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that the service is expecting content type other than XML, like JSON?   The default behavior for `WebClient` is to assume `content-type` is `application/xml`.

Here's the relevant [source code for WebClient.java](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cxf/trunk/rt/frontend/jaxrs/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/client/WebClient.java):

```
protected Response doInvoke(String httpMethod, Object body, Class<?> responseClass, Type genericType) {

    MultivaluedMap<String, String> headers = getHeaders();
    if (body != null) {
        if (headers.getFirst(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE) == null) {
            headers.putSingle(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE.toString());
        }
    } else {
        headers.putSingle(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.WILDCARD);
    }
    if (responseClass != null && headers.getFirst(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT) == null) {
        headers.putSingle(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE.toString());
    }
    resetResponse();
    return doChainedInvocation(httpMethod, headers, body, responseClass, genericType, null, null);
}
```

If so, you can set the content type on `WebClient` using the [`type()`](http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/client/WebClient.html#type%28javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType%29) method.  For example, to have the client produce JSON:

```
WebClient client = WebClient.create("http://MY_SERVER:9090/admission/services/processing");

client.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);

Admission a = new Admission();
a.setCode("73935282");

Response r = client.path("/admission").put(a);
```